# Using if condition to display data in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

How print value in this code:

```
<li class="price-val">{{ $value->price ? '$value->price &#128; month<span class="price-fea-ct">&#42;VAT Included</span>':'$value->price &#128; month' }}</li>
```

$value->price variable is have 0 & 9 value respectively.but it does print value.print $value->price just.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
<li class="price-val">
@if ($value->price) 
{{{ $value->price }}} &#128; month<span class="price-fea-ct">&#42;VAT Included</span>
@else 
{{{ $value->price }}} &#128; month
@endif
</li>
```

However for me the condition doesn't make sense - if price is 0 you will display `0 / month` and it does not seem to be logical

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors, try this:

```
<li class="price-val">
    {{
         $value->price ?
         $value->price . '&#128; month <span class="price-fea-ct">&#42;VAT Included</span>' :
         $value->price . '&#128; month'
    }}
</li>
```